# how can i connect to my mysql server using localhost?

Tags: mysql, localhost

this might sound stupid, but i never experienced such thing, im developing on my localhost, but i have my server with 1 and1, how can i connect to my database on my server using my localhost, what will the host be? thanks

Comment: You will need to ask 1&1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using the string "localhost" as the hostname or the IP address if you know it.

If that doesn't work you could contact the [1 & 1 customer support](http://order.1and1.com/xml/order/Contact).

Comment: no i cnt use localhost, because im not developing on my server on 1and1, im using my own computer, but i want to access my database that on my 1and1 server, shall i just put the ipaddress!!!

Comment: @getaway: You can try the IP address, but that will only work if there is no firewall. Otherwise you should upload your code to the server. Or install your own database on your own machine.

Comment: yeh it works, thanks, my ip address!! is that good thing or bad thing, deos that mean i need install a firewall!!

Comment: @getaway: Generally you should have as few ports open as possible on your server.

Answer (score 0):

host will be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`(This is IP address for localhost). I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that mysql is actually listening on localhost (127.0.0.1).
You may be connecting over your public IP.

If you want to test running mysql only on localhost, this quick howto shows you
what to put in your /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

Use 'localhost' as your host when connecting between db and localhost. In connecting your server to your database, follow the instructions from your localhost server website.